# StripeException: Invalid API Key provided: Stripe.Net

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, stripe.net

My program successfully creates a token and passes it. It then creates all of the relevant information for a customer for Stripe.

```
                var customer = new StripeCustomerCreateOptions();

            customer.Email = $"{user.Email}";
            customer.Description = $"{user.Email} [{userId}]";
            customer.PlanId = planId;
            customer.SourceToken = stripeToken;
            customer.Quantity = 1;
            var customerService = new StripeCustomerService();
            StripeCustomer stripeCustomer = customerService.Create(customer);
```

I confirmed that all of those are passing their values properly to the customer object but, I get the error in the title. What am I missing?

Comment: if you require more information to figure it out I will make edits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ugh... I am an idiot... I was missing a line to set my API secret key like so:

```
StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(StripePrivateKey);
```

Comment: First time I didn't notice - PRIVATE key not set.